# MySQL: Best way to handle user balance?

Tags: php, mysql, normalization, database-normalization

Short question: 
What's the best way to handle user balance and user transactions?

I'd probably create a transaction table where I'd log every transaction and then select over it to get the actual user balance. But wouldn't that be slow after thousand of transactions by the same user? Would a view speed the things up?

Or should I store the user balance in the user table and update it with a mysql transaction while I'm inserting in the transactions table?

Dont't panic. I"m not planing to handle real money.

Comment: your question is much better suited for https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ — I think it might explain the downvotes. SO is mainly about solving practical problems, not theoretical choices

Comment: Thank you. I'm new so please excuse me for not knowing that. In future I'll do better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, calculating the balance on the fly from all the transactions would be quite slow; a view would make queries easier to write, but won't have much impact on performance (a view is just a shorthand, it's not an actual table).

You should go with the second method: put the current balance in the `account` or `user` table, separate from all the transactions, and update it whenever you add a transaction.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do it like this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) for this.  Whenever new record is added to `transactions` table, trigger updates `users` table.

Comment: Thank you. Good solution but I accepted the second answer because I don't want to use triggers in this case. In case of switching the DBMS it's easier without them I think.